# SQL Server CTE incremental function for two loops?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Presently I have the following loop function in SQL Server 2008:

```
DECLARE @I int = 0
DECLARE @X int = 0
DECLARE @withdrawlCosntant float = 0.25
DECLARE @signups int = 0

WHILE @I<=12
BEGIN
  WHILE @X <= 24
  BEGIN
     SET @X = @X + 1

     SET @signups = (SELECT Singups FROM TraineeCredits WHERE I = @I AND X = @X)

     INSERT TraineeForecast(I, X, Signups)
     VALUES (@I, @X + 1, @signups - @singups * @withdrawlConstant)
  END

  SET @X = @I
  SET @I = @I + 1
END 
GO
```

While this works, it is extremely slow for me.

- I have a pretty good idea how I could achieve the first loop within a CTE using a seed  and a UNION ALL with an incremental function, however I was wondering if it is possible to do both loops in a CTE?
- I know I can use a execute() to launch the CTE within a loop.
- But is there a way to run two incremental functions like this in a CTE?

EDIT:
How would I create a way to push the rows?
Basically I and X are like axises in a pivot.

And we have the rows:

```
(I,X,Signups) 
(0,1,2) 
(0,2,4) 
(0,3,1)
```

How would i push it down for the next I=1?

```
(I,X,Signups) 
(1,1,0) 
(1,2,2) 
(1,3,4) 
(1,4,1)
```

Remembering that there is a max X of 24.  For I=2 it would look like:

```
(I,X,Signups) 
(1,1,0) 
(1,2,0) 
(1,3,2) 
(1,4,4) 
(1,5,1)
```

Comment: "it is extremely slow" - I'm not sure I see why. The innermost statements execute less than `13 * 25` times, and that many `SELECT`s and `INSERT`s shouldn't really take any time at all. How long does this code take to run?

Comment: Sorry, I'm horribly confused on the "push" issue.  Are the rows you're showing the rows in the TraineeCredits table, or the rows that are returned by the query?  Let's simplify the problem and say that I goes from 0 to 3 and X goes from 1 to 5 (X is never 0, right?).  When I run my query, the results are: (0, 1, 2)
(0, 2, 4)
(0, 3, 1)
(0, 4, 3)
(0, 5, 1)

(1, 2, 1)
(1, 3, 5)
(1, 4, 4)
(1, 5, 4)

(2, 3, 3)
(2, 4, 1)
(2, 5, 2)

(3, 4, 2)
(3, 5, 1)  What are saying the results should be (I'm just making up the Signups value here)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, in fact, implement the data insert through CTE's.

```
WITH i_values as
  (
    SELECT 0 as i
    UNION ALL
    SELECT i_values.i+1
    FROM i_values
    WHERE i_values.i <= 11
  ),
x_values as
  (
    SELECT 0 as x
    UNION ALL
    SELECT x_values.x+1
    FROM x_values
    WHERE x_values.x <= 23
  )  
, i_x_values as
  (
    SELECT i_values.i, x_values.x
    FROM i_values
    FULL OUTER JOIN x_values
    ON x_values.x >= i_values.i - 1
  )
INSERT INTO TraineeForecast
SELECT i_x_values.I, (i_x_values.X)+1, TraineeCredits.Signups - TraineeCredits.Signups * 0.25
FROM TraineeCredits
INNER JOIN i_x_values
ON TraineeCredits.I = i_x_values.I AND TraineeCredits.X = i_x_values.X;
```

Here's a <kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64a12/4)</kbd>.

Comment: This is by far the clearest example I have seen of a CTE function at work. thank you! :)

Comment: If you could explain the following line:    
ON x_values.x >= i_values.i - 1

That would be great.

Comment: You're welcome! First, I figured out what iterations of i and x values you are using. You can check the values in the updated fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64a12/5

Comment: Sure! First, I manually calculated the i and x values using the original WHILE loops in your code. I saw that the values of i ranged from 0 to 12 and the values of x ranged from (i-1) to 24. So, when i = 12, x goes from 11 to 24. Therefore, the condition ON x_values.x >= i_values.i-1

Comment: I have a question: Basically if I do an Insert to TraineeCredits instead of TraineeForecast does the select get affected? i.e. it is self-referencing

Comment: You can insert into TraineeCredits. In that case, to my knowledge, the query would operate based on whatever data was in the table when you started running the query.

Comment: So it will not work if I insert new rows with the CTE? i.e. it will only work in the original state. Hmmm so perhaps a CTE function isn't appropriate then. since the table does feedback loop within itself.. is there any way to approach this problem?

Comment: I think my best bet would be to run a single loop CTE function within a single WHILE loop. It might not be the most desirable solution.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a CTE.  Create a Numbers table in your database.  A Numbers table is just a table with a single column containing sequential integers from 0 to some arbitrarily large number (mine goes to 9999).  Leave it in your database, because it is useful for all kinds of things.

```
create table Numbers(Number int)
insert Numbers
SELECT TOP 10000 row_number() over(order by t1.number) -1 as N
FROM master..spt_values t1 
CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2
```

Now you can run a query like this:

```
insert TraineeForecast(I, X, Signups)
select ni.Number I, nx.Number + 1 X, tc.Signups - tc.Signups * @withdrawlConstant Signups
from Numbers ni
cross join Numbers nx
left outer join TraineeCredits tc on tc.I = ni.Number and tc.X = nx.Number
where ni.Number between 0 and 12
and nx.Number between 1 and 24
and nx.Number > ni.Number
```

The cross join generates a result for every combination of I and X, which can be joined to your TraineeCredits table to get the Signups.

Check out a SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e6994/1

Comment: that looks really good. I will run the query and keep coming back with more feedback. I actually have a fn_Numgenerator

Comment: Okay it appears to be working, but I have one last query. If I want to push the signup values down i.e.
if we have the following:
(I,X,Signups)
(0,1,2)
(0,2,4)
(0,3,1)

By push I want to do the following:
(1,1,0)
(1,2,2)
(1,3,4)
(1,4,1)

How can I achieve that? Would it require something completely else.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing.  Can you clarify?  Maybe edit the question so you have more space and formatting available.

Comment: So when I is 0, X goes from 1 to 24.  When I is 1, X goes from 2 to 24.  When I is n, X goes from n+1 to 24.  Do you mean you want to fill in with zeros the rows where X is between 0 and n?

Comment: Yes, and push the values down. So if X=0 and I=0, and Signups = 120
then I=1, X=1 is also 120, while I=1 and X=0 is 0.

Comment: To be honest you do not need to set (0 to n) to 0, it can be empty/skipped.

Answer (score 0):

you can generate the 'two loops' with recursive cte in this way:

```
WITH r AS (
    SELECT 1 AS n, 1 AS m
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CASE WHEN m<24 THEN n ELSE n+1 END, 
        CASE WHEN m<24 THEN m+1 ELSE 1 end  
        FROM r WHERE n*m<288
)
SELECT * FROM r
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```